# RemoveDuplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which has columns (A,B) (C,D) (E,F) (G,H) (I,J). I need to sort each 2-tuples then remove duplicates in that 2-tuple column then move to the next till I complete (A,B) to (I,J).
I have no issue with (A,B) columns BUT when I come to (C,D) macro crashes with the message

```
Run Time Error - 1004 " Application defined or object defined error
```

I have tried the code below - X,Y as Strings and I as Integer.
I have changed the `Columns:=Array(I,(I+1))` to `Columns:= I` as well

```vba
If I = 1 Then
  Sheets("sorted").Range(X & "1" & ":" & y & "9999").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(I, (I + 1)), Header:=xlYes
  ' Columns:=Array(7,8), Header:=xlYes|
Else
  Sheets("sorted").Range(X & "1" & ":" & y & "9999").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(I, (I + 1)), Header:=xlYes
End If
```

Expected result - I want to remove duplicates from each set of columns (A,B) to (I,J) . Instead if am getting error message as described above.

Comment: Would help to show the rest of your code - for example how you set X and y.  And where is `I` coming from?

Comment: X As String, y As String, I As Integer

Comment: str = "ABCDEFGHIJ"  ' Column Headings
For I = 1 To 9 Step 2
numb = I * 10
X = Mid(str, I, 1)
y = Mid(str, (I + 1), 1)
Sheets("sorted").Cells(2, I) = ""
Sheets("sorted").Cells(2, (I + 1)) = ""
With ActiveSheet.Sort
      .SortFields.Clear
      .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("sorted").Range(X & "2"), Order:=xlAscending
      .SortFields.Add Key:=Worksheets("sorted").Range(y & "2"), Order:=xlAscending
      .SetRange Worksheets("sorted").Range(X & "2" & ":" & y & "9000")

Comment: .Header = xlYes
      .Apply
 End With
 MsgBox " x1 and y9999.... " & X & "1" & ":" & y & "9999" & " I = " & I
 Cellupdates X, y
 If I = 1 Then
 Sheets("sorted").Range(X & "1" & ":" & y & "9999").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(I, (I + 1)), Header:=xlYes ' Columns:=Array(7,8), Header:=xlYes|
 Else
 Sheets("sorted").Range(X & "1" & ":" & y & "9999").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=I, Header:=xlYes ' Columns:=Array(7,8), Header:=xlYes|
 End If

Comment: The FUNNIEST or WEIREDEST thing is the above code works 100% correctly on Mac BUT on Windows I get problems which I have explained above. Same Code absolutely no change. I ran teh code at Work on Windows - problem. Came home ran on Mac - with Abs NO changes - Boom ! worked 100% correct.